# Android. Локализация

Tags: локализация, android

Нужно сделать так, что бы при некоторых локалях использовался по дефолту русский, а при некоторых английский. Вижу такое решение: во всех соотвествующих папках values-xx, вставить файл такой же как и в values-ru, а в других такой же файл как и в values-en. Но ведь их довольно много... можно как то по - другому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да, можно разместить в ресурсах **values-xx** с указанием кода нужной локали(коды локалей можно посмотреть вот в [этой таблице](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)  во второй колонке), а строковые ресурсы разместить в **values-en** и **values-ru**. 
При запуске приложения читаем локаль из **values-xx**  и пишем

```
Locale locale = new Locale("код прочитанной локаили");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

**UPD:** английский язык я бы посоветовл сделать по умолчанию и разместить в папкe values без модификаторов.

**UPD[2]:** Как я понял из задачи, то есть группы локалей, которым нужно показывать английский интерфейс, а другим группам русский. 
Так вот, в тех группах, где нужен русский интерфейс вы в **value-xx** пишите строковый ресурс с локалью "ru", аналогично для английской. 
Когда будете считывать локаль

```
String localeCode =  getResourses().getString(R.string.locale)
```

андроид сам определить от куда взять.  А потом выполняете   **Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);...**

Comment: Как я понимаю, сначала я считываю текущую локаль, потом в зависимости от этого, выполняю данный код, где вместо "код прочитанной локали" ставлю en или ru?

Comment: немного не так. пояснил в обновлении

Comment: Я так понимаю, рецепт всё же такой:

Делаем строковые ресурсы в каждой локале, и делаем строку например с именем base_locale. в ней указываем локаль откуда брать данные. А вместо "код прочитанной локаили" вставляем `getBaseContext().getString(R.id.base_locale)`.

Что приведёт к нужному результату.

О! А когда писал не было нового апдейта. Может всё же аякс подключат, как на стекоферфлове?

Answer (score 1):

UPD. Прочитав еще раз, понял что не подходит.
Больше подойдет предыдущий ответ на вопрос: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934542/1659629)

**Оригинал:**[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934092/1659629)

**Мой краткий перевод-пересказ:**
Идеальным решением было бы использование множества модификаторов имени для папки ресурсов из одной группы `(values-ru-ua-en-fr)`, но разрешены только модификаторы из разных групп `(drawable-en-hdpi)`
Но это все еще не означае, что вам придется бесполезно копировать кучу одинаковых файлов.
На помощь тут приходят ссылки на ресурсы (*ориг*. **alias resources**).
Ссылка на [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)

Comment: мне кажется это решение не подойдет, потому что там строковые ресурсы будут иметь разное название.

Comment: @Andreich согласен. но пока оставлю ответ, для общего развития.