# Android не работает локализация для регионов

Tags: android, локализация

Создаю string-en и string-ru соответственно. Так же есть дефолтная папка. Всё работает, только проблема в том, что когда захожу с разных русских регионов, напримр укр или Казахстан то получаю ресурсы по умолчанию а не русские. В чем проблема? Как обойти это, не создавая отдельно подпапки для каждого региона?

Comment: Куда заходите из разных регионов?

Comment: Изменяю язык телефона, и открываю приложение

Comment: "string-ru" это название файла?

Comment: Нет. Названия у них string у всех, только в разных папках расположены. Для наглядноси написал, это и так понятно.

Comment: Было бы понятно, не спрашивал бы.

Comment: Всё логично - Вы выбираете казахский, но в ресурсах нет `-kz` - поэтому берётся дефолтный ресурс. Положите русский в дефолтную папку и он будет везде, кроме отдельно указанных. Или смотрите [вопрос о том же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/322429/11515)